# 'more' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, module

I'm in the python `help` then `modules`.

Then any module I type I get the

'more' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Is there an easy answer? Thanks

Python 3.4 on windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: `more` is a pager program installed by default on *nix/BSD based systems. AFAIK, this isn't installed by default on Windows. Python seems to be trying to use `more` to show the help pages (just a hunch). How did you install Python?

Comment: Windows inherited a very simple `more` from DOS. Usually, the full path of the program is `C:\Windows\System32\more.com`.

Comment: via IDLE, very basic noob install. I got a number of warning prior that I don't get on Linux

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek found the `C:\Windows\System32\more.com` file, is where it is supposed to be. Python can't find this path, maybe in the help module section within the python files? seems like a lot of trouble, could be a rabbit hole

Comment: What happens if you just type `more` in command prompt and hit enter?

Comment: @Arc676 the classic `'more' is not a recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`.

so.. i would just have windows recognize this file somewhere via a systems path?

Comment: Does `more.com` exist in `System32`? Is `.COM` among the list of extensions of environment variable `PATHEXT`? Is the full directory name of `System32` an element in enviroment variable `PATH`?

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek very nice work you two. beautiful. the `C:\Windows\System32\` was missing from the Path variable from that one time I was noob hacking it. it all makes sense now.

thanks it all works now, the module help and the more command.

Answer (score 1):

Try this command in cmd:

```
python -m pydoc modulename ***-type the module name here
```

Note: This will only work if you run cmd as admin otherwise you will get the same error (the 'more' error)

[image]